# How do I .show text that is contained within a paragraph of a given class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text, show

The objective is for the text to show with the .show jQuery method when the document loads.  What is wrong with the code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML)
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Spaghetti Kung Fu Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.title").show('slow');
});
</script>
<p class="title">Spaghetti Kung Fu</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to hide it before showing *(using show)* http://jsfiddle.net/9hqrk1jb/1/

Comment: Besides the fact that you aren't hiding the `p` to begin with; the `p` is just going to be displayed immediately anyway. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Try: _$("p.title").hide().slideDown('slow');_

Comment: Any `.title` rule in `style.css`?

Answer (score 0):

It is working but to see its effect hide your `p` at first.

```
<p class="title" style = "display:none">Spaghetti Kung Fu</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<style>
.title{display:none}
</style>
<p class="title">Spaghetti Kung Fu</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.title').fadeIn()
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c51zuL02/

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the `<p>` first before you can show it.

Use CSS to set `display:none`.

[See example here](https://jsfiddle.net/vuuyf9et/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p.title").show('slow');
});
```

```css
.title {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title">Spaghetti Kung Fu</p>
```